# Finding difference between two rows in BQ SQL

Tags: sql, function, google-bigquery

I'm still fairly new with SQL but practicing daily to get better. This one is throwing me for a loop a little bit, hoping someone could help out here since I've had success on this platform before.

I'm trying to get a new column in a table that is the difference between two values on separate rows (specifically, they are timestamps, as I'm trying to get the amount of time spent looking at something by subtracting the two values). My timestamps are in UNIX values, but I'll be converting those to datetime and then I am guessing the TIME_DIFF or DATE_DIFF function will be used to calculate the actual time difference.

The idea would be to have the difference of row 1 and row 2 appear in a new column on row 1. I've seen the LAG function in other posts, but this seems to do the opposite of what I need, i.e., finds the difference between row 1 and row 2, and adds it as a new column in row 2, meaning row 1 difference will be 0.

It must also only be contained within each participant_id, meaning that the process repeats itself when a new unique participant_id is encountered (if I understand this is a PARTITION BY function, but I'm not sure how to string it together).

Here's an example of what I need:

| Row | participant_id | event_timestamp | time_spent (minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2:15 PM | 5 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2:20 PM | 10 |
| 3 | 12345 | 2:30 PM | null |
| 4 | 67890 | 10:30 AM | 15 |
| 5 | 67890 | 10:45 AM | 5 |
| 6 | 67890 | 10:50 AM | null |

Any help with this would be a life saver. Thank you in advance!

I have not tried anything yet, as I don't know how to string the different functions together to make this work.

Comment: If you want to compare a row with the next row, rather than the previous row, then use LEAD rather than LAG

Comment: @NickW Thank you! A commenter posted the same below. I hadn't learned this function, but obviously very useful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by combining the LEAD window function with a subquery.

```
SELECT participant_id, event_timestamp, next_event_timestamp-event_timestamp as time_spent 
from (select participant_id, LEAD(event_timestamp, 1) 
OVER (PARTITION BY participant_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) 
AS next_event_timestamp from table) as subquery;
```

To explain this query in more detail:

1. The main query selects the participant ID, the event_timestamp, and then subtracts the difference between the time of one event and the next. However, since we do not have the time between each event, this must be calculated with a subquery (or nested query) - which essentially creates a second table that we are querying using the FROM clause.
2. The subquery is selecting the participant id, and then using the LEAD function to display the next event timestamp in a separate column (this is then subtracted from the previous event timestamp in the main query). PARTITION BY is used to make sure that this is segregated by participant id - i.e. we do not want the differences between one participant id and another.

You may also find the following [resource](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-lead/) helpful to understand the LEAD function in more detail.

Comment: Thank you Michael! I will try this and report back. This seems to make a lot of sense to me, and thank you for the detailed explanation-- very useful as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't leave a comment on the other answer because I don't have 50 reputation, but I think it needs to be modified to work.  The subquery isn't pulling in the event_timestamp field, only the calculated next_event_timestamp field.   This means the main SELECT statement won't find an event_timestamp field.  Simple fix:

```
SELECT participant_id, event_timestamp, next_event_timestamp-event_timestamp as time_spent 
from (select participant_id, event_timestamp, LEAD(event_timestamp, 1) 
OVER (PARTITION BY participant_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) 
AS next_event_timestamp from table) as subquery;
```

I don't normally work with BQ SQL, but this should be an alternate solution that uses TIMESTAMP_DIFF instead of a subquery.  It still uses the LEAD function, but relies on TIMESTAMP_DIFF to calculate the difference in minutes between the current event_timestamp and the following event_timestamp.  It is also by participant ID, so you should get a null value if the participant doesn't have anymore event_timestamps after the current one.

```
 SELECT participant_id, event_timestamp,
, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_timestamp, LEAD(event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY participant_id order by event_timestamp asc), MINUTE) as time_spent
FROM #tmp_participants
```